# How do I filter query results in Watson Discovery using Python?

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I've been trying to use the Watson Discovery Tool through python but I'm not having much luck. I would like to query the Watson Discovery News Library and filter `enriched_text.categories.label` for `/business and industrial` and `language` for `en`. I was able to do all this through the website but don't know how to filter in Python.

Here's my code:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

discovery = DiscoveryV1(
    version='2018-08-01',
    username={my username},
    password={my password},
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api')

#Here I don't know how to filter.
discovery.query(discovery, "system", "news-en", filter=)
```

Thank you for the help